# PHP PCRE match punctuation but not ++

Tags: php, regex, pcre, negative-lookbehind

I tried to search for an answer to this for a while but could not find it. There were many posts related to matching text which is not preceeded by certain text but none seems to work for this case where + is matched but it is allowed only when preceeded by a single + (eg. ++)

I am trying to remove punctuation marks from text but let two consecutive ++ signs to stay but single + signs to disappear

```
$text="Hello World! C+ C++ C#";
print_r(preg_replace('/(?!\+\+)[[:punct:]]/', ' ', $text));
```

Results in (I am not sure why the latter + is removed? can somebody explain?):

> Hello World  C  C+  C

If I try:

```
$text="Hello World! C+ C++ C#";
print_r(preg_replace('/(?!\+)[[:punct:]]/', ' ', $text));
```

Result is:

> Hello World  C+ C++ C

But the result I want is:

> Hello World  C C++ C

Thanks

UPDATE: I realized that I should probably mention that I will have other characters which I want to avoid. I may have oversimplified the question. For example I may want to avoid # also thus result would be

> Hello World  C C++ C#

the solution should be easily expandable. I am sorry about the inconvenience caused by this missing information.

Comment: The problem arises from a scenario like this `++++`. Whatcha gonna do then?

Comment: Then just enumerate the special cases inside a non-capturing group before `(*SKIP)(*F)` - `preg_replace('/(?:[#^]|\*{3}|\+{2})(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:punct:]]+/', ' ', $text);`

Comment: `preg_replace('\b(\+(?!\+)|[^\P{P}#])', ' ', $text)` you have to add special characters inside character class. E.g. to exclude `!` : `[^\P{P}#!]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of choices here, one being:

```
(?<!\+)[+#](?!\+)
# with lookarounds making sure no + is after/behind
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vA5wA6/1).

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$regex = '~(?<!\+)[+#](?!\+)~';

$string = 'Hello World! C+ C++ C#';
$string = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

---

Another one would be to use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism (which is a bit faster in this example):

```
\+{2}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[+#]
# let two consecutive ++ always fail
```

See a demo for this one on [**regex101.com as well**](https://regex101.com/r/vA5wA6/2).

**Last but not least**:
If you want to add characters/expressions that should be avoided as well, you can put them in a non-capturing group and let this one fail:

```
(?:\#|\+{2})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|
[[:punct:]]
```

Yet another [**demo on the wonderful regex101.com site**](https://regex101.com/r/vA5wA6/3).

Comment: This obviously does not match the rest of the punctuation characters. I could change [+#] with [[:punct:]] and that solves that problem. But I now see that I should have told in the question that I will also need to add more punctuation characters to be avoided. How do I do that? For example if I want to avoid # also ?

Comment: I really liked the (*SKIP)(*FAIL). It solves all my problems. BUT I have a question. The perl manual says match leading till (*SKIP) cannot be part of any match of pattern. It says regex engine skips forward to this position and retries. So I don't understand what does (*FAIL) do exactly? because perl manual says it causes backtracking. Which as far as I understand means going to the next character after the 1st character which was matched. But why do we need (*FAIL) if (*SKIP) already skips the ++ characters?

Comment: Evren, the main point is that when used together these verbs cause the current match to be totally discarded from the match object and - what is highly important - proceed analyzing the string after that discarded match. Backtracking means attempting to try another pattern variation granted the pattern has unknown width quantifiers or alternation.

Comment: Wiktor, I can see what it does :) What I meant was that I don't really understand that it should do this from the perl manual. It makes me think that it starts again 1 character after the original match. But nevermind. Just for your reference, the manual I meant was here -->   http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Backtracking  --> "it realizes its mistake and starts over again one character after where it had the tentative match"
and for (*FAIL) "This pattern matches nothing and always fails. It can be used to force the engine to backtrack. It is equivalent to (?!), but easier to read"

Answer (score 2):

Your first regex `(?!\+\+)[[:punct:]]` doesn't work because it looks for two consecutive `+` signs in a negation - at each position - then asserts next immediate character to be a punctuation mark. When it sees `C++` , cursor being on next to the first `+` sign, this match succeeds since there is no `+` after second `+`. So first `+` is matched.

```
Hello World! C+ C+|+ C#
                  ^ Cursor here - (?!\+\+)[[:punct:]] is matched
```

Regex:

```
[[:punct:]]++((?<=\+)(?<=[^+]\+))
```

A possessive match in addition to a conditional positive lookbehind assertion will do the job.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG8xS8/2)

Explanation:

```
[[:punct:]]++   // Match punctuation marks possessively - won't allow backtrack
((?<=\+)        // Start of a conditional statement, check if last match is a `+`
    (?<=[^+]\+) // If yes, it should not be preceded by another `+`
)               // End of conditional
```

PHP:

```
preg_replace('@[[:punct:]]++((?<=\+)(?<=[^+]\+))@', ' ', $text)
```

**Update**

If `+` singes are always preceded by some letters there is a much shorter solution:

```
\b\+(?!\+)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first code snippet works like this: a punctuation symbol is found and if it is not a starting point for a `++` sequence, it is matched and removed. So, the second `+` in `C++` is matching, and is removed.

You may match and *discard from the match using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs* what you want to keep and just match what you want to remove:

```
preg_replace('/\+{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:punct:]]+/', ' ', $text);
```

Adding more characters - just in case:

```
preg_replace('/(?:[#^]|\*{3}|\+{2})(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:punct:]]+/', ' ', $text);
               ^^^                ^
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/78HCwZ)

**Details**:

- `\+{2}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - Matches 2 `+` symbols and then discards them from the match
- `|` - or
- `[[:punct:]]+` - matches one or more punctuation symbols.

In the replacement pattern, we just replace with a space.

Comment: I consider it to be the cleanest the easiest to expand approach.

Comment: This is very nice, but it has a problem. I want to replace found characters with space character. This simply removes them. A+B becomes AB

Comment: See update, it can be helped using the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique. See the updated demo - http://ideone.com/78HCwZ

Comment: Now you made a duplicate.

Comment: @revo `\+{2}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[+#]` != `\+{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:punct:]]+`

Comment: You followed main idea of @Jan's answer. Side of alternation is not that important.

Comment: You also may want to remove your first comment here as you didn't mean current regex by that.

Comment: @revo: you are mistaken, I did not even know Jan mentioned that in his answer. Please stop posting irrelevant comments or I will ask to remove them.

Comment: You always check others answers.

Comment: I have 2 kids and a nagging wife with me - I have time to check answers? I got a feedback, and I provided a solution - that is all. You think I do not know how and when to use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`? Think that, just let me go to bed in a more or less quiet mood.

Comment: It is just a question, not worth arguing over. I would have given correct answer to both of you if possible. I gave the answer to Jan because I believe he was the first to mention it. The (*SKIP)(*FAIL) is quite elegant but I did not quite understand why one needs (*FAIL) exactly (as I commented at jan's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three cases here to match plus sign.
The double plus has to be matched to move past it.

*Note - This follows left to right rules about plus signs. With no rules but these.*

Find:

`[^\P{P}+]|(\+\+)\+|\+`

Replace:  `'$1 '`

Explained

```
    [^\P{P}+]           # Punctuation but not plus
 |  
    ( \+\+ )            # (1), Plus with leading ++
    \+
 |  
    \+                  # Any old plus sign
```

Which can be reduced to

```
   [^\P{P}+]           # Punctuation but not plus
|  
   ( \+\+ )?           # (1), Plus with optional leading ++
   \+
```

Comment: You wrote `\+` in a side of alternation. So it will match all `+` signs regardless of their way of presence. Your first regex was fine.

Comment: @revo - I know it matches any +. But it will passively match `+++` if available. Unfortunately the rules have to be resolved left to right. A stand alone `++` would seem to be just that. Then compare that to `++++++++++++` or `++++` then some rules have to be considered.